# How to display database information based on value selected from dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have successfully created a dropdown list based on my database information. What I would like to do is display the options' information on a separate page when I select the option from the dropdown list.

This is my working connection and dropdown list code:

`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "user: " . $_SESSION['username'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from Products');
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();



    if($results){

        echo "<select name='products'>";
        echo "<option value= '' selected='selected'> Please Select Product </option>";
        foreach($results as $row){
    echo "Product: " . $row['ProductName'] . " </br>";
        echo "<option value= " . $row['ProductID'] ." > " . $row['ProductName'] . " </option>";
    }  
    echo "</select>";
        $prodID = $IDInfo["ProductID"];
        $prodName = $NameInfo["ProductName"];
    }
```

`

and this is my editProd.php page where I would like to display the database information depending on the selected option.

```
 if(isset($_POST['edit']))
        {
            $prod = $_POST['products'];
            echo "This is the value selected : " . $prod . "<br>";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from Products');
            $stmt->execute();

            $results = $stmt->fetchAll();



            foreach($results as $row){

               if($row[""] = $prod)                
                {
                    echo "<br> " . $row['ProductID'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . "<br>"; 
                } 

                else 
                {
                    echo "Invalid Selection";
                }

            } // end of the foreach loop



        }
```

My result is the following:

This is the form that will allow you to edit the product

This is the value selected : 2

2 Samsung

1 dell

... Ideally what I would like is for "2 Samsung" to be the only information displayed in this case.  If the value selected is 1, I would like for the display to be "1 dell"

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: replace ` if($row[""] = $prod)  ` with ` if($row["ProductID"] == $prod)  ` or use the better option Darshan supplied.

Comment: Thank you, This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `WHERE` condition and bind the parameter, e.g.:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from Products WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $prod);
$stmt->execute();
```

This would return the details for selected product only.

Comment: I included your changes, but now I don't get a result at all. Perhaps it has to do with the binding?

Comment: Maybe you are passing the name of the product and not the id? In that case, you need to search by name or pass the id..